# Is it ever harmful to set a database owner in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, security

There are a bunch of databases on one of our SQL servers that have no owner.  Generally speaking, is it harmful to give them one?  For example:

```
USE dbName;
GO

EXEC sp_changedbowner 'sa';
GO
```

I know sa may not be the best choice, but it is just an example.  My primary concern is whether or not creating an owner when there is none may cause issues with software that can currently connect OK.

Comment: what is the impact if a database does not have an owner?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be using DDL instead of backward compatibility stored procedures:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::dbName TO sa;
```

And the owner of the database (never mind `sa`) should probably not be the account that your applications use, so this should not really have any effect on your applications. If it does then you should update the connection strings your application uses (which shouldn't be a major change) and make sure the account has sufficient - but not God - privileges.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  However, " My primary concern is whether or not creating an owner when there is none may cause issues with software that can currently connect OK."

Comment: @Eric the problem is there is a difference between "none" and "invalid" - why do you think there is NO owner?

Comment: I think you're right.  I noticed the issue with Right-Click-->Properties and got the common "Cannot show requested dialog.  Property Owner is not available for Database 'dbName'. This property may not exist for this object, or may not be retrievable due to insufficient access rights."  But I just ran a query: select name, owner_sid from sys.databases.  I did get an sid for the database, but when I use SUSER_SNAME(owner_sid) instead, I get a NULL in the 2nd column.  So, invalid owner, correct?  Thanks!

Comment: @Eric yes, correct.

Comment: OK, thanks.  So, is it even possible to have "no owner?"  These all have an sid, but about half of them (moved from another server by someone else) are NULL when I call SUSER_SNAME(sid).

Comment: No, there is always an owner (it just may not be valid). What your situation means is that it is owned by a login that exists on the old server but has not been migrated to the new server. Just set them all to `sa` and be done with it unless you need those logins for other reasons (however if the login is not crucial to exist on the current server in the first place, it's very questionable whether it should have ever owned the database, never mind should own it now that it's been moved).

Comment: Right... I knew that the logins must have come from the old server; hence the mentioning of the old server :)  I just wanted to be really sure that setting the problem ones wouldn't cause problems for running applications.  I REALLY appreciate your help!

Comment: The answer is there, thanks.  If we've got any more to say, let's [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7996/discussion-between-eric-and-aaron-bertrand)

Answer (score 6):

By declaring a database owner, you give that user total control over a database.  Database owners have full access to all data within all tables, be able to `CREATE/ALTER/DROP` objects within the database, etc.   This can be good or bad, depending on your requirements.  Typically, I set all database owners to 'sa' to provide a default owner.  As 'sa' already has sysadmin rights, granting database ownership doesn't grant escalated security.

Comment: So I'm hearing that adding an owner to a database without one only ADDS access rights to the database.  It will not damage any existing rights.  Is that correct?

This seems trivially obvious.  However, I'd rather really understand this than be sorry.

Comment: @Eric if the current owner is invalid then it can't possibly be being used by your application. Where did the database come from?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that always give an owner to database. Since some tools complains when database does not have an owner, for example [diagram tool](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1816/getting-started-with-sql-server-database-diagrams/).

[image: Diagram Tool, owner complain image]
Also using already powerful user like "sa" for this purpose is better like Mike Fal suggested.

Comment: There is a difference between NO OWNER and INVALID OWNER. This isn't a case of NO OWNER.